# SSIS Package - "Subquery returned more than 1 value" - Inserting one record into a table

Tags: ssis

SSIS on SQL Server 2008 R2

I have inherited an SSIS package that is failing when importing a spreadsheet. The part of the failure is in a data flow that consists of :-
  * an Excel Source Data Flow Component
  * a Derived Column Data Flow Component
  * an OLE DB Destination Data Flow Component

[image]

I have added data viewers on the two flows, and these show only 1 row on each.
[image]

The table that I'm importing into is empty.

I'm not sure what else to look at. Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to run a profiler trace to see the statement being sent to SQL Server? If so, could you post it along with any other queries that are defined in the package? Thanks

Comment: Does the table have triggers on it?

Comment: @billinkc it DOES have a trigger on it. - Updating my question.

Comment: The trigger is doing something dumb relative to what the data indicates ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case there was a trigger that trying to update one of the rows. The unfortunate thing was that the query in the trigger returned more than one row in the subquery.

As it turned out for me the trigger was only relevant for one particular supplier (an IF condition in the trigger), also luckily for me, the previous occupant of my position hadn't reviewed this trigger, and it was no longer needed.

Removed the trigger. However in other scenarios I would have had to modify the trigger to return one row only.